# Is promise constructor function necessary or can it be avoided?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

According to [Promise - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise),

> The constructor is primarily used to wrap functions that do not
>   already support promises.

1. At a low level, the functions that already support `promises` would
   be doing this right i.e constructing a `promise` using `Promise` and returning it back?
2. Is there a better way to create a `promise` other than using the `Promise` constructor function?
3. Eventually, you have to register a `callback` somewhere right? I mean you can't avoid having a `callback` that at-least `resolves`? In other words, we have to wrap it like this somewhere in the library correct?

Comment: The original promise mechanism used "defer", but it had weaknesses.  Your point about the nature of promises and callbacks is accurate - promises can be seen as just an easier way to manage your callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

> At a low level, the functions that already support promises would be doing this right i.e constructing a promise using Promise and returning it back?

Yes. Maybe. At a low level, we don't know how functions that already support promises do construct those. Imagine what the `Promise` constructor itself uses to construct promises…

> Is there a better way to create a promise other than using the Promise constructor function?

No, there's no other way accessible to JS. But as MDN notes, you should rarely ever need to do this yourself, and rather just use other functions that already create promises for you (which by themselves of course go through the Promise constructor somehow).

> Eventually, you have to register a callback somewhere right? I mean you can't avoid having a callback that at-least resolves?

Not necessarily. At a low level, you could also register any arbitrary data structure that allows to resolve a promise, this does not necessarily need to be a callback function. (It is however indeed equivalent in power to registering the `resolve` callback function).

For example the native implementation of the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (afaik the first native API that directly returns promises) will hardly create JS callback functions anywhere to resolve its promises.

Answer (score 1):

1. At the lowest level? Yes, probably.
2. Depends on the context. If the value you want to resolve the value to is already available, then you'd use `Promise.resolve(theValue)`. If you want to wait for multiple promises you'd use `Promise.all(allThePromises)`. And of course every call to `.then` returns a new promise.
3. If you want to do anything with the value of a promise, then yes, you have to pass a callback to `.then`. <del>There is no other way to get the value.</del>

Having said all that, [ES2017 introduced *async functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which are basically syntactic sugar for promises. `async` functions always return a promise and you can use `await` to unwrap promises. Example:

```js
async function get() {
  return await Promise.resolve(42);
}

get().then(console.log);
```

Comment: So `async function test(){ await sth(); return whatever;}` is *no way* ? ;)

Comment: Those damn new shiny features... :P

Comment: @Nishant: Yes, like most things (e.g. a `for` loop could be considered syntactic sugar for a `while` loop).

Comment: @FelixKling, I am not talking about doing anything with the value of a promise, but if the promise has to be resolved at some point, (most likely at the completion of some event), you need to pass the `resolve` as a callback to some API right?!

Comment: @Nishant: "you need to pass the `resolve` as a callback to some API right?!"* That's the usual application. But you could also do `new Promise(resolve => resolve(42))`. It wouldn't be the best way to do it, but you could do it. E.g. maybe you are implementing a caching functionality and resolve immediately if it's in the cache: `new Promise(resolve => { if(inCache) { resolve(value); } else { fetchValue(resolve); })`.

Comment: @nishant or you call it directly yourself ( *resolving*)

Comment: I don't see what `async function`s have to do with any of this. They're syntactic sugar for `then` calls (and maybe for `Promise.resolve(…)`), but they cannot replace the `new Promise` constructor in any way.

Comment: @FelixKling Caching should be done by storing promises, not by storing the `value`. `fetchValue` should return a promise, not take a callback.

Comment: @Bergi: Regarding async: You'd consider it a different way of creating a promise. Regarding caching: Of course.  It's just an example of what is possible. (and if `fetchValue` returned a promise you wouldn't be using `new Promise` anyway `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`)

Comment: @FelixKling I don't consider `then` or `Promise.all` as a different way of creating a promise, no. At least not in the same sense as constructing it using `new Promise`.

Comment: @Bergi: Then we have to agree to disagree :) I'm probably looking at it at a higher level than you are (i.e. which are the different APIs / syntax features that produce promises).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. At a low level, the functions that already support promises would be doing this right i.e constructing a promise using Promise and returning it back?

The eventual goal is that even the low-level APIs within Node.JS will be using the Promise syntax so there will be no need for callbacks. The PromiseJS community considers the constructor syntax to be a polyfill for this eventual behavior. [Source.](https://www.promisejs.org/#construction)

In practice, this is obviously not the case.  Browsers, Node.JS and other Javascript runtime environments make heavy use of callbacks, and so the Promise constructor is used.

> 2. Is there a better way to create a promise other than using the Promise constructor function?

Yes- but this depends on application.

Most obviously, if you are using an API which already returns a promise, you can use `.then()` and `.catch()` syntax to chain promises together.

There are also a number of libraries which extend the default Promise functionality and provide convenience methods for increased performance and readability. For instance,  [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) (a common PromiseJS library) offers a way to evaluate the result of multiple promises created concurrently for faster overall runtime.

You can also construct Promises from other paradigms which simplify code- for instance [Promise.Promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) which converts a callback function into a Promise one, or [Observable.toPromise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) which converts Observables to promises.

> 3. Eventually, you have to register a callback somewhere right? I mean you can't avoid having a callback that at-least resolves? In other words, we have to wrap it like this somewhere in the library correct?

Similar to the answer to your first question, this is a symptom of code currently using the callback paradigm.  If all libraries used Promises on a lower level, this wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Im not shure how *one could use Promises on a lower level* . The promises `resolve()` is a callback too. And were not talking about nodejs and bluebird here, theyre not realy related to promises.

Comment: @Jonasw Native promises are in the es6 specification- so technically speaking all es6 applications could use promises instead of callbacks in every instance. Obviously this has problems for backwards compatibility- hence the constructor syntax.

Comment: yep. But arent Promises relying on callbacks i mean `.then(callback)` , `reaolve(whatever)` ...

Comment: @Jonasw As for Bluebird, while it is not included in native promises, it is a common implementation of the Promise library used by developers.  It has significant performance and readability benefits, so I figured it was worth mentioning.

Comment: "*offers concurrent execution of promises for faster overall runtime*" - please stop spreading the false thought that a promise is something that can be executed. (Also I have no idea to which Bluebird feature you refer here)

Comment: @derek no its rather misleading here

Comment: @Jonasw again- no.  Promises could hypothetically be atomic.  For instance, the browser and node.js (and other runtime environments) could just as easily return promises instead of using callbacks.  Practically speaking, however, all libraries will use the constructor syntax on some level.